# Dojo/Dijit SimpleTextarea and RadioButton (with Spring-JS integration) validation via 'required' attribute not supported, yet works in FireFox?

Tags: dojo, dijit.form, spring-js

I'm having some issues with integrating the DOJO javascript library with Spring framework. Specifically, the problem is how to validate textareas and radiobuttons. I am using Spring-Js library to decorate standard html form elements e.g.

```
<form:input path="actionDescription" id="actionDescriptionId"/>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
                            elementId : "actionDescriptionId",
                            widgetType : "dijit.form.SimpleTextarea",
                            widgetAttrs : { disabled : false,
                                            required: true,
                                            rows: "4",
                                            cols: "60",
                                            placeHolder: "Enter description of fault",
                                            style: "width:auto;height:50px;"    
                                 }}));  
                    </script>
```

I have been developing in FireFox (using Firebug) and I've only now realised (after looking at the Dojo/Dijit documentation) that dijit.form.SimpleTextArea doesn't support the 'required' attribute. I never checked this before as it all worked fine in FireFox. I have a form button which when clicked will validate all decorated elements, and in firefox all components including text areas and radiobuttons will pop up with a nice looking tooltip indicating the field is required. The line of code is use is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Spring.addDecoration(
                new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration({elementId:'proceed', event:'onclick'}));
    </script>
```

This is great as it prevents forms submission until all required fields are completed. The radiobuttons pop up with a nice message saying the user must select one of the options, and the text area pops up with a nice message telling the user to type something. However, it doesn't work in Safari or IE. Validation doesn't work for text areas and radiobuttons on these other browsers, and so server side validation is used to redirect the user back to the form. Although this works, I much prefer to prevent form submission in the first place and have consistent error reporting rather than a mix of client and server side error messages.

I'm really struggling to understand why it works in firefox when the dijit textarea components aren't supposed to support the 'required' attribute? I like the idea of using the spring-js to enhance basic components, but I don't really understand how decorating an element with digit.form.SimpleTextarea with validation works in FireFox when according to the digit documentation, there isn't any supported validation?

I was wondering if any other Spring developers who use the Spring-Js/Spring-DOJO integration have come across this behaviour and if they have any deeper understanding of how it works. What I really want is to have the textareas validated in all browsers including IE.

Comment: After some digging, I think the reason that the radiobutton and textarea validation in firefox is working is because of HTML5 form validation support. As HTML5 isn't supported in both my IE and Safari versions, that explains the difference in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the issue was with HTML5 in Firefox providing the validation behaviour for textareas and radiobuttons. Since my target audience is IE (and possibly IE6), I can't rely on HTML5 form validation, and therefore I'm stuck with the fact that DOJO's Dijit widgets for textareas and radiobuttons don't support validation.

Thanks to http://www.harelmalka.com/?p=137 I have created a workaround to enable validation on textareas. For radiobuttons however, I have provided a default selection to negate the need for validation.